# lolcat - How can I put the symbol <---- on the opposite side?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to put it this way. I want the date to be seen, inside the arrows:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo
echo -ne "----->" | lolcat; date | lolcat;
echo -e "<-----"
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want the date to be seen, inside the arrows

`date` generates output with one newline character at the end, you need to remove it. Additionally if there is no trailing newline in the input, `lolcat` will add it (at least in my Debian 9). Therefore I guess you should prefer a single `lolcat` to process everything.

```
(echo -n "----->"; date | tr -d '\n'; echo "<-----") | lolcat
# or
echo "----->$(date)<-----" | lolcat
```

The first variant uses `tr` to remove newlines (in fact one trailing newline) from the output of `date`. Single `lolcat` processes the stream from the entire subshell (`(…)`).

The second variant embeds the output of `date` into the argument to `echo`. The trick here is command substitution (`$(…)`) deletes all trailing newline characters.

Since [`printf` is better than `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618), a more elegant solution may be:

```
printf -- '----->%s<-----' "$(date)" | lolcat
```

Note [double-dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) is very useful here.

In Bash you can use `<<<` to pass a string to stdin of a command without explicit `echo` or `printf`. Like this:

```
lolcat <<< "----->$(date)<-----"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Y con el paquete  "apt-get install toilet toilet-fonts" , se podrá hacer un script en bash.? "toilet -f smbraille Bienvenido  --filter metal"

Comment: Lo quiero para la presentación de mi Script. echo "Bienvenido" con el paquete  toilet -fonts.

Comment: @Liiam Please take our short [tour] to see how the site is supposed to work. If you have a new question then [ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). It should be in English. See [ask] first.